# c:forEach - ui:include - dataTable issue

Tags: jsf, jstl

I have some code like:

```
<c:forEach>
    <ui:param name="orderItemsList" value="#{appPortfolioBomBean.orderItemsByVdcMap[vdc.internalId]}" />
    <ui:include>

....
   </ui:include>
</c:forEach>
```

and the component I include contains a **datable** which renders some value based on `orderItemsList` parameter.

The problem is that **the dataTable is rendered only for the LAST item from `<c:forEach>`...**

Do you see what I am doing wrong? I am sure is something about jsf/jstl tags but cannot find out... I've tried to use `ui:repeat` instead of `c:forEach` but the same issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

I'm using icefaces and for this specific issue they recommends:

> Yes, I've seen the same problem with ui:repeat and dataTable. 
>   Try to replace ui:repeat with `<ice:panelSeries>`.

Replaced and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try UI repeat instead

```
<ui:repeat value="${bean.list} var="variableName">
   <!--YOUR CODE ->
</ui:repeat>
```